# jQueryUI draggable onto fixed element

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I want to use jQueryUI's draggable to drag a table row onto a fixed navbar. The dragged element has css properties:

```
element.style {
   position: absolute;
   z-index: 200;
}
```

and the fixed navbar has properties

```
#player {
   position: fixed;
   opacity: 1;
   z-index: 100;
}
```

Even though the z-index of the draggable element is higher, it still doesn't appear in front of the fixed navbar. Is it impossible to get an `position:absolute` element in front of a `position:fixed` element in HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsbin.com/eWoNASE/1/edit

Hard to debug your problem without a live example, but this works for me:

```
  <div id="wrap">
  <div id="fixed">
    <p>hi</p>
  </div>
  <div id="draggable">
    <p>Drag me around</p>
  </div>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
#wrap { position: relative; }
#fixed {
   position: fixed;
   opacity: 1;
   z-index: 100;
}

#draggable {
   background-color: red;
   position: absolute;
   opacity: 1;
   z-index: 200;
}
```